# JavaScript Standards for IO

Tags: discussion, code-golf, rules

When it comes to JavaScript [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), there tends to be two schools of thought regarding IO (specifically printing).

Some golfers will use functions such as `alert`, `document.write`, and `console.log` (explicit printing), whereas other golfers will rely on the console implicitly logging the return value of statements executed in it (implicit printing).

I think it's worth discussing what the standard should be so that developers who make use of explicit printing are not at a disadvantage against developers using implicit printing. Of course, anyone posting a code golf could always explicitly override the standard.

Personally I believe that JavaScript code golf should work irrespective of where it's executed* (`<script>` element, browser console, node, etc), which means that explicit printing would be required.

<sub>* some golfs will require exceptions to this due to the nature of the different environments</sub>

Answer (score 7):

Here is my proposal for a standard:

- Use `alert` if the code runs in web browser (for example if it modifies DOM), or just uses core JavaScript (as it's easy to claim it's a browser code in this case). It should be used just once, as message boxes are annoying when shown multiple times (this means you should prepare a buffer for `alert`).
- You can almost always use `console.log`. You need to if you work with non-browser environments, such as Node.js. For example, if code uses `require` in order to load stuff like Underscore.js, it has to use `console.log`. It's longer than `alert` however, so it probably won't be used outside of Node.js context.
- Use `print` if you write code for SpiderMonkey, without web browser. I don't know why you would want to, but you can. Just tell that code requires SpiderMonkey, because web browsers use `print` for something else (printing on printer, that is).
- Use `document.write` if you need to output HTML, or want to output in multiple statements, or something. Otherwise, `alert` is shorter.
- Write a function when task asks you to, and return the value.
- Never use implicit print statement. That's cheating in my opinion, and won't work outside of dev console. If you really want to, make Node.js code, and say it runs with `-p`. It also would waste 1 character ([On "interactive" answers and other special conditions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions)).

Comment: With `node` they can use `-p` just as with `perl` and `ruby`. Not using neither that +1 penalty is clear cheating.

Comment: @manatwork: Interesting, I didn't knew about this feature. Well, the standard for Perl golfing is that flag wastes the number of characters needed to write them. For example, `-p` is 3 characters (including a whitespace). Could be fine if you use Node.js, and you specify `-p`, I guess.

Comment: According to [On “interactive” answers and other special conditions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions), we count it 1.

Comment: @manatwork: Thanks for information. I find it interesting, but I guess this is fine.

Comment: More specifically, we count it 1 if the script is eligible for a `-e` invocation in the presented form. Which is most often the case, yet not always.

Comment: `console.log` should be the only valid answer. With Node.js it is _always_ stdout (by default) and relatively modern browsers support console messages. All relevant JavaScript engines use `console.log`. Aside: [`print` also works in v8's d8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284207/console-log-with-standalone-v8-d8).

Comment: I completely disagree with the first point that people should limit the use of `alert`, because it is 'annoying'. This website is about golfing code, not in any way about UX.

Answer (score 0):

I propose we adopt a standard I/O library with published specifications. This allows platforms with different I/O models to use variations of this standard library to just work. I have seen this approach used in textbooks with good results.

Answer (score -3):

I have no idea how that's done in JavaScript, but for multi-language challenges, I don't think it should get any preferential treatment. The common case is “write to stdout”, and it should stick to that unless specifically allowed by the problem.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't typically *have* a standard out.