# Is the PHP opening tag mandatory in byte count?

Tags: discussion, scoring, php

After answering the first time on PPCG on ["Source code ecological footprint"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58692/source-code-ecological-footprint/58782#58782) I had a little discussion about it. I found [it's OK if your program throws notices or warnings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/php-and-warnings). But I couldn't find anything about the [opening PHP tag](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

My question is: Do I need to include and count it? If yes, is the short tag `<?` instead of `<?php` allowed, as it must be enabled via `--enable-short-tags` or *php.ini*?

In any case, could somebody please add an explanation in their answers on *why* it is needed or not? I think this might be useful for other users as well as currently all different versions can be found here in PHP answers.

---

Interesting read as well: [Running PHP with `-r` instead of code tags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/running-php-with-r-instead-of-code-tags). If a program is run from the command line using `-r` option it doesn't need the opening tag, like:

```
php -r "echo 'ok';"
```

<sub>I hope this is not a duplicate, found nothing related when searching for the tag and word "PHP".</sub>

Comment: Related -- [Using libraries in solutions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/188/42963) / [Language handicap](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/185/42963) / [On "interactive answers and other special conditions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/273/42963) / [Shebangs: yes or no?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/84/42963) / [Should non-standard compiler flags be used in code counts?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19/42963)

Comment: In the linked [Running PHP with `-r` instead of code tags](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/running-php-with-r-instead-of-code-tags), there is agreement that `php -r` is acceptable without code penalty. It follows that neither `<?` nor `<?php` are required.

Comment: @es1024 Please add this comment as an answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2424), running programs via commands such as `php -r "code here"` is acceptable without penalty.

Since `<?` and `<?php` are both unneeded (and in fact not allowed) when using `php -r`, it follows that neither tags are required.

Comment: But if I use `<?=` to save on `echo` that still counts as three bytes, because it cannot be done with `php -r` but has to be in a file, right?

Comment: @YetiCGN Yes. We're effectively treating `-r "code here"` and `filename here` as separate languages.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the use of the `<?` short tag: since [it's on by default](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.language-options), I think the use of `<?` instead of `<?php` is okay for code golf.