# Does HTML count as a programming language?

Tags: discussion

In challenges like this: ["Hello, World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/104064#104064)

it is possible to answer using HTML. Everywhere else it is possible to answer the code golf using HTML, is it allowed?

According to [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/is-html-css-a-programming-language) CSS is allowed but they never answered HTML

Comment: I've voted to close this as a dupe. Additionally, HTML alone is not sufficient to count as a programming language [according to our consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/42963), so for non-fixed-output challenges it's (generally) not an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No, but you *can* use HTML in [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity).

As explained in [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3639/44713) and explained [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages#comment19797_7518) by Martin, "fixed-output" ([kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenges) do *not* require programming languages to be solved.