# How do mandatory flags in new languages get counted

Tags: discussion, scoring

This is different then [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions)

I am writing a new code-golf language and am thinking about making two modes. One would be stack and other tacit. However you would have to specify what one you want to use. If I require one flag or another would it still be counted in the byte count?

Answer (score -3):

## Yes Count it!

Even if it is mandatory then you will be posting snippets without it

Answer (score -3):

## No don't count it!

It is mandatory and you could just make 2 versions to avoid the rule

Comment: Also, for later reference: Please don't post answers you disagree with. (the two you posted are inherently contradictory)  Playing devil's advocate doesn't always work okay, leave it to the people who actually support a side.