# Non-standard command line calls

Tags: discussion, policy

Note this isn't about command line flags, which already have a [consensus here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/76162).

There was a [recent PHP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180389/76162) involving multiple PHP files. Normally, programs with multiple files are either using one file to import/execute/retrieve data from the others, or else are all called with the interpreter like:

`./lang file1 file2 file3`

However, in this answer, the poster specified that the command to execute the program would be:

`php file1;php file2`

which caused arguments that this was actually just running two programs, or that it should instead count as the Bash language.

Is this a valid way of executing a submission? Does this still count as the PHP language? Do we have a policy on what are the valid ways to execute a submission?

Comment: One could interpret each sequential invocation of _n_ files as its own sub-language, like done with command-line flags ...