# Ruleset for RGS's Golfing Showdown - competition is over!

Tags: discussion, code-golf

## RGS

**RGS** stands for **RGS's Golfing Showdown**, a golfing competition.

### The competition has ended, final leaderboard at the end of this post!

## 1 - The format

The **RGS** will be a virtual golfing competition with 5 [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges.

#### 1.1 - Post dates

The 5 challenges are scheduled for 24th and 28th of February, 3rd, 7th and 11th of March and will be posted the closest to 8 a.m. UTC I manage to.

## 2 - Challenges

Each challenge is a regular [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge open to the whole codegolf.SE community.

#### 2.1 - Themes

The 5 challenges will have varied themes, including [maths](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maths), [integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer), [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string), etc.

#### 2.2 - Sandboxing

The RGS challenges will be sandboxed usually.

## 3 - Participation

#### 3.1 - User eligibility

Any codegolf.SE member is eligible to participate in this competition.

#### 3.2 - Entering the competition

Any user that submits eligible submissions to each of the 5 challenges is entered into the competition by default.

#### 3.3 - Eligible submissions

For each given challenge, a solution has to satisfy the following requirements to be considered *eligible* for the RGS competition:

1. A solution has to be submitted in the first 96 hours after the challenge is posted;
2. A solution must not be in any of the *restricted languages* (see **section 4**);

## 4 - Restricted languages

This section explains the restrictions on per-challenge languages "allowed" for the RGS competition. These restrictions apply only to submissions that are for the challenge. A submission in any of the *restricted languages* is still a valid [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) submission!

#### 4.1 - Purpose

The purpose of creating *restricted languages* is to force users to use more than one prominent language in order to compete in the RGS.

#### 4.2 - Choosing the restricted languages

Challenges 2, 3, 4 and 5 will have a minimum of `3` *restricted languages*. The *restricted languages* for challenge `i + 1` are computed as per the following algorithm:

1. Start with no *restricted languages* and with a counter as `0`.
2. Sort the submissions to challenge `i` per byte count, keep ties.
3. Take all the languages that provided solutions with the lowest byte count available:

   1. Define those as *restricted languages*.
   2. Increment the counter by `1`.
   3. Remove all the languages added to the *restricted languages* from the submission list created in 2.
   4. If the counter is smaller than `3` and we have less than `5` restricted languages, go back to 3.
4. Ta-da!

#### 4.3 - Dialects

For the purposes of the *restricted languages*, different versions and/or dialects are counted as the same language. As examples, `Python 2` and `Python 3` count as the same language, as do `APL Classic` and `APL Dyalog Extended`.

#### 4.4 - Example

Say that for challenge 3 we have the following submissions, with the respective byte-counts:

```
5 bytes: 05AB1E, Jelly
6 bytes: APL Classic
28 bytes: Python 2
31 bytes: Ruby
40 bytes: PHP
120 bytes: brainfuck
137 bytes: Java
```

Then the *restricted languages* for challenge 4 would be `05AB1E, Jelly, APL` and `Python`.

## 5 - Scoring

#### 5.1 - Final entry

At the fifth challenge, a user who wishes to be considered in the final RGS ranking must choose one of his/her eligible submissions (as in **section 3**), per challenge, to be accounted for in the final competition score. These choices must be listed at the end of the chosen submission of the 5th challenge.

#### 5.2 - Per-challenge scoring

Each chosen submission is given score equal to its byte count 96 hours after the challenge was posted.

#### 5.3 - Final scoring

The competition score is calculated by summing up the byte scores of the eligible submissions that the user chooses.

#### 5.4 - Tie-breaking

In case **5.3** results in a tie, the following criteria are used for tie-breaking:

1. The user with more unique languages in the 5 chosen submissions wins;
2. The user that submitted earlier more times over the course of the 5 challenges wins;
3. The user with the earlier submission for challenge 5 wins.

## 6 - Prizes

#### 6.1 - Main competition winner

The winner of the main competition will win a `200` reputation bounty awarded by me. Sorry if this isn't much!

#### 6.2 - Style points for surprising answers

I will also award `50 x 5` reputation bounties, one per challenge, to the answer that surprises me the most. This is entirely subjective and I reserve myself the right to attribute this bounty to whatever answer I please.

*Note that because of my lack of knowledge about the full bounty mechanics, I was forced to start a 100 rep bounty on [my second challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200250/75323), instead of the advertised 50 rep.*

#### 6.3 - Sponsoring

If you wish to sponsor a language you really like, or just want an excuse to offer a bounty for an answer in a particular language, you may sponsor one of the challenges, or the whole competition, by commenting below under what conditions you also want to award a bounty to someone.

Please take into consideration that consecutive bounties have to be double the previous bounty.

## 7 - Rankings

This section will be updated as the competition moves forward, to reflect the partial rankings of the challenges.

#### 7.1 [Challenge 1 - binary multiples](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/199995/75323)

The bonus style points were awarded to [this answer in Roj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200356/75323), a toy programming language I created a *long* time ago.

[Leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18691/75323)

#### 7.2 [Challenge 2 - strings within character classes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200250/75323)

The bonus style points were awarded to [this Shakespeare Programming Language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200426/75323) for being such a literate answer and because, I quote, `"Is I as big as the sum of The cube of a big big cat the cube of The sum of A big cat a cat?"`.

[Leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18692/75323)

#### 7.3 [Challenge 3 - help me write portuguese](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200485/75323)

I [did not manage to award the bonus style points](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18690/75323) for this challenge, unfortunately.

[Leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18693/75323)

#### 7.4 [Challenge 4 - inverting matrices modulo m](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200685/75323)

The bonus style points were awarded to [Arnauld's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200688/75323) for actually computing the inverse of the matrix, instead of randomly generating matrices or going over *all* the possible matrices.

[Leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18660/75323)

#### 7.5 [Challenge 5 - computing the set of all set partitions with fixed sizes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200861/75323)

The bonus style points were awarded to [this Jelly answer by Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200883/75323) for being a Jelly submission from a member that I associate with Java, 05AB1E and Whitespace but definitely not with Jelly.

[Leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18694/75323)

## Final leaderboard

The competition is now over and these are the final standings! Thanks to everyone who participated and I hope you enjoyed it!

1. [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan), 103 bytes
2. [Embodiment of Ignorance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84206/embodiment-of-ignorance), 120 bytes
3. [Expired Data](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85908/expired-data), 143 bytes
4. [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil), 236 bytes
5. [Nick Kennedy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42248/nick-kennedy), 281 bytes
6. [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder), 376 bytes
7. [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen), 466 bytes
8. [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld), 491 bytes

Comment: I'll be part of the sandbox if you ping me before the challenges are to be posted.

Comment: I'll be in that sandbox too if y'all don't mind.

Comment: x86 ASM is not a golfing language, but is not on the list. It has a ton of one-byte builtins but string processing is long, so it rarely wins good golfing challenges.

Comment: @S.S.Anne the sandbox chatroom has been created.

Comment: @Lyxal the sandbox chatroom has been created.

Comment: Where is it?...

Comment: @S.S.Anne https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104796/rgss-golfing-showdown-sandbox

Comment: I'm confused. Does "For users who participated in the sandbox of the given challenge, submissions must have been submitted no earlier than 24 hours after the challenge was posted." mean that we have to wait a day or we can only post it for a day?

Comment: @S.S.Anne You have to wait a day

Comment: Your Challenge 1 links back to this meta Q.  Is that intended?

Comment: @L.F. it was not intended; fixed.

Comment: I don't think I understand the rules to identify restricted languages. Will the list of restricted languages be included in each challenge?

Comment: @RobinRyder yes. At the bottom of challenge 2, you will se the "restricted languages" for it. Same for challenges 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Is 4.2 only applied at the time of posting? Or would a new low-byte answer to challenge i *after* i+1 has been posted change the list of restricted languages?

Comment: @JonathanAllan a new low-byte answer to challenge i does no affect resctricted languages for challenge i+1: the "restricted languages" for challenge i+1 are computed from the eligible submissions to challenge i. When challenge i+1 is posted, new solutions to challenge i are no longer eligible :)

Comment: Unfortunately all competitive golfing languages I know tie at 9 bytes (at the 3rd place).

Comment: And now what about the "surprising" answers?

Comment: @S.S.Anne I edited the post

Comment: Can you add who the points would've gone to in challenge 3 had you been able to award the bounty and why?

Comment: @S.S.Anne to be honest, I have no idea. That is why I was taking so much time to award it... I didn't find the regex-based solutions particularly enticing... From the others, I liked all of them more or less the same.

Comment: @RGS I'll write up a solution and then you can put that up there.

Answer (score 1):

## Challenge 4 leaderboard

Positions marked with a * are non-eligible because of restricted languages.

```html
 <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> <tr><td>1.</td><td>Expired Data</td><td><a href="https://github.com/tkwa/Sledgehammer" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Sledgehammer</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200706">6</a></td></tr><tr><td>2.</td><td>Bubbler</td><td><a href="http://jsoftware.com/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">J</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200834">16</a></td></tr><tr><td>*3.</td><td>Jonathan Allan</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Jelly</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200701">22</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>J42161217</td><td><a href="https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/" rel="noreferrer">Wolfram Language (Mathematica)</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200687">23</a></td></tr><tr><td>*5.</td><td>Nick Kennedy</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Jelly</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200691">25</a></td></tr><tr><td>6.</td><td>Jonathan Allan</td><td><a href="https://github.com/lmendo/MATL" rel="nofollow noreferrer">MATL</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200704">26</a></td></tr><tr><td>7.</td><td>Bubbler</td><td><a href="https://docs.python.org/3/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Python 3</a> + <a href="https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html" rel="nofollow noreferrer">SymPy</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200856">33</a></td></tr><tr><td>7.</td><td>Noodle9</td><td><a href="https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/developer/index.html" rel="nofollow noreferrer">SageMath</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200690">33</a></td></tr><tr><td>9.</td><td>Embodiment of Ignorance</td><td><a href="http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Magma</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200720">34</a></td></tr><tr><td>10.</td><td>Neil</td><td><a href="https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Charcoal</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200708">41</a></td></tr><tr><td>11.</td><td>Robin Ryder</td><td><a href="https://www.r-project.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">R</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200693">68</a></td></tr><tr><td>12.</td><td>Giuseppe</td><td><a href="https://www.r-project.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">R</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200844">83</a></td></tr><tr><td>13.</td><td>Graham</td><td>WIN+APL</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200709">114</a></td></tr><tr><td>14.</td><td>Nick Kennedy</td><td><a href="https://www.r-project.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">R</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200700">128</a></td></tr><tr><td>15.</td><td>Arnauld</td><td>JavaScript (ES6)</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200688">206</a></td></tr><tr><td>16.</td><td>Kevin Cruijssen</td><td>Java 8</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200786">261</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Challenge 1 leaderboard

```html
<table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> <tr><td>1.</td><td>Expired Data</td><td><a href="https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E" rel="noreferrer">05AB1E</a></td><td>6</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200009">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>1.</td><td>a'_'</td><td><a href="https://github.com/A-ee/w" rel="nofollow noreferrer">W</a></td><td>6</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200004">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>3.</td><td>Jonathan Allan</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Jelly</a></td><td>7</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200043">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>Embodiment of Ignorance</td><td><a href="https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Japt</a></td><td>9</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200132">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>Nick Kennedy</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Jelly</a></td><td>9</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200050">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>Giuseppe</td><td><a href="https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Gaia</a></td><td>9</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200042">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>Kevin Cruijssen</td><td><a href="https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/instructions.md" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Stax</a></td><td>9</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200037">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>Kevin Cruijssen</td><td><a href="https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt" rel="nofollow noreferrer">MathGolf</a></td><td>9</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200033">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>Shaggy</td><td><a href="https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Japt</a></td><td>9</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199998">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>10.</td><td>isaacg</td><td><a href="https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Pyth</a></td><td>10</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200117">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>10.</td><td>Luis Mendo</td><td><a href="https://github.com/lmendo/MATL" rel="noreferrer">MATL</a></td><td>10</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200008">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>12.</td><td>Bubbler</td><td><a href="https://www.dyalog.com/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">APL (Dyalog Unicode)</a></td><td>13</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200130">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>12.</td><td>DeathIncarnate</td><td><a href="https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Burlesque</a></td><td>13</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200021">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>14.</td><td>Neil</td><td><a href="https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal" rel="noreferrer">Charcoal</a></td><td>19</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200013">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>15.</td><td>Jonah</td><td><a href="http://jsoftware.com/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">J</a></td><td>22</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200063">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>16.</td><td>andytech</td><td><a href="https://www.perl.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Perl 5</a></td><td>23</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200029">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>17.</td><td>Jo King</td><td><a href="https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Perl 6</a></td><td>29</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200053">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>18.</td><td>I.T Delinquent</td><td><a href="https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell" rel="nofollow noreferrer">PowerShell</a></td><td>31</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200142">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>18.</td><td>Mathgeek</td><td><a href="http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">GolfScript</a></td><td>31</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200041">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>20.</td><td>Christian Sievers</td><td><a href="https://www.haskell.org/" rel="noreferrer">Haskell</a></td><td>36</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200015">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>20.</td><td>Kirill L.</td><td><a href="https://www.ruby-lang.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Ruby</a></td><td>36</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200014">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>22.</td><td>Arnauld</td><td>JavaScript (ES6)</td><td>37</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200002">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>23.</td><td>Post Rock Garf Hunter</td><td><a href="https://www.haskell.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Haskell</a></td><td>38</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200242">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>23.</td><td>640KB</td><td><a href="https://php.net/" rel="noreferrer">PHP</a></td><td>38</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200023">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>23.</td><td>Robin Ryder</td><td><a href="https://www.r-project.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">R</a></td><td>38</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200005">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>26.</td><td>JungHwan Min</td><td><a href="https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Wolfram Language (Mathematica)</a></td><td>40</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200054">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>26.</td><td>Mitchell Spector</td><td><a href="https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Bash</a> + Core utilities</td><td>40</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200031">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>28.</td><td>xnor</td><td><a href="https://docs.python.org/2/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Python 2</a></td><td>42</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200182">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>28.</td><td>ovs</td><td><a href="https://docs.python.org/2/" rel="noreferrer">Python 2</a></td><td>42</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200011">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>30.</td><td>xibu</td><td><a href="https://gcc.gnu.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">C (gcc)</a></td><td>48</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200096">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>30.</td><td>Surculose Sputum</td><td><a href="https://docs.python.org/3/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Python 3</a></td><td>48</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200064">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>32.</td><td>J42161217</td><td><a href="https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Wolfram Language (Mathematica)</a></td><td>49</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200017">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>33.</td><td>chau giang</td><td><a href="https://nodejs.org" rel="nofollow noreferrer">JavaScript (Node.js)</a></td><td>50</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200247">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>33.</td><td>Galen Ivanov</td><td><a href="https://github.com/gtownsend/icon" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Icon</a></td><td>50</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200075">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>35.</td><td>Galen Ivanov</td><td><a href="http://www.red-lang.org" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Red</a></td><td>52</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200036">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>35.</td><td>Mitchell Spector</td><td><a href="https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/" rel="noreferrer">Bash</a> + Unix utilities</td><td>52</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200006">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>35.</td><td>Noodle9</td><td><a href="https://docs.python.org/3.8/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Python 3.8 (pre-release)</a></td><td>52</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200001">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>38.</td><td>my pronoun is monicareinstate</td><td><a href="http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc" rel="nofollow noreferrer">C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)</a></td><td>53</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200027">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>39.</td><td>Giuseppe</td><td><a href="http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)</a></td><td>55</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200049">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>40.</td><td>t-clausen.dk</td><td>T-SQL</td><td>57</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200012">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>41.</td><td>Kevin Cruijssen</td><td>Java 10</td><td>58</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200022">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>42.</td><td>Neil</td><td><a href="https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d" rel="noreferrer">Retina 0.8.2</a></td><td>68</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200016">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>43.</td><td>S.S. Anne</td><td><a href="https://gcc.gnu.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">C (gcc)</a></td><td>80</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200040">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Challenge 2 leaderboard

In the ranking below, submissions marked with a `*` are not eligible for the competition because they used restricted languages (see **4** above).

```html
<table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> <tr><td>*1.</td><td>Grimmy</td><td><a href="https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E" rel="nofollow noreferrer">05AB1E</a></td><td>17</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200287">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>*2.</td><td>Nick Kennedy</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Jelly</a></td><td>18</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200285">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>*3.</td><td>Kevin Cruijssen</td><td><a href="https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands" rel="nofollow noreferrer">05AB1E</a></td><td>19</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200265">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>isaacg</td><td><a href="https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Pyth</a></td><td>21</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200301">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>Luis Mendo</td><td><a href="https://github.com/lmendo/MATL" rel="nofollow noreferrer">MATL</a></td><td>21</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200264">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>6.</td><td>Jonathan Allan</td><td><a href="https://github.com/barbuz/Husk" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Husk</a></td><td>22</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200376">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>*6.</td><td>Jonathan Allan</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m" rel="nofollow noreferrer">M</a></td><td>22</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200344">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>8.</td><td>Embodiment of Ignorance</td><td><a href="https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam" rel="nofollow noreferrer">CJam</a></td><td>23</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200333">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>9.</td><td>640KB</td><td>x86-16 machine code</td><td>25</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200340">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>10.</td><td>Mathgeek</td><td><a href="http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">GolfScript</a></td><td>27</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200279">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>11.</td><td>Arnauld</td><td><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600" rel="nofollow noreferrer">CP-1610</a> machine code (<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellivision" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Intellivision</a>)</td><td>28</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200270">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>11.</td><td>Bubbler</td><td><a href="https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS" rel="nofollow noreferrer">QuadS</a></td><td>28</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200269">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>13.</td><td>DeathIncarnate</td><td><a href="https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Burlesque</a></td><td>29</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200258">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>14.</td><td>anatolyg</td><td>x86 machine code</td><td>30</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200379">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>14.</td><td>ovs</td><td><a href="https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Befunge-98 (PyFunge)</a></td><td>30</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200267">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>16.</td><td>Neil</td><td><a href="https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Charcoal</a></td><td>31</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200266">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>17.</td><td>Christian Sievers</td><td><a href="https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Pyth</a></td><td>34</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200274">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>18.</td><td>Jo King</td><td><a href="https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Raku</a></td><td>37</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200253">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>19.</td><td>Xcali</td><td><a href="https://www.perl.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Perl 5</a> <code>-p</code></td><td>42</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200288">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>20.</td><td>Kirill L.</td><td><a href="https://www.ruby-lang.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Ruby</a> <code>-n</code></td><td>45</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200357">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>21.</td><td>ovs</td><td><a href="https://www.haskell.org/" rel="noreferrer">Haskell</a></td><td>48</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200259">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>22.</td><td>Jonathan Allan</td><td><a href="https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Labyrinth</a></td><td>50</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200342">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>22.</td><td>Mitchell Spector</td><td><a href="https://gcc.gnu.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">C (gcc)</a></td><td>50</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200290">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>24.</td><td>Noodle9</td><td><a href="https://gcc.gnu.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">C (gcc)</a></td><td>58</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200262">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>25.</td><td>wilkben</td><td><a href="http://julialang.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Julia 1.0</a></td><td>60</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200297">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>25.</td><td>Arnauld</td><td><a href="https://nodejs.org" rel="nofollow noreferrer">JavaScript (Node.js)</a></td><td>60</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200252">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>27.</td><td>RGS</td><td>Haskell</td><td>64</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200256">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>28.</td><td>Noodle9</td><td><a href="https://gcc.gnu.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">C++ (gcc)</a></td><td>70</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200300">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>29.</td><td>Robin Ryder</td><td><a href="https://www.r-project.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">R</a></td><td>73</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200283">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>29.</td><td>Surculose Sputum</td><td><a href="https://docs.python.org/3/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Python 3</a></td><td>73</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200273">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>31.</td><td>Neil</td><td><a href="https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Retina</a></td><td>74</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200277">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>32.</td><td>Expired Data</td><td><a href="http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc" rel="nofollow noreferrer">C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)</a></td><td>76</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200261">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>32.</td><td>Kevin Cruijssen</td><td>Java 8</td><td>76</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200260">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>34.</td><td>Mukundan</td><td><a href="https://docs.python.org/3.8/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Python 3.8 (pre-release)</a></td><td>87</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200272">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>35.</td><td>Nick Kennedy</td><td><a href="http://www.riscos.com/support/developers/manual_index/basic.html" rel="nofollow noreferrer">BBC BASIC V</a></td><td>92</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200337">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>36.</td><td>S.S. Anne</td><td><a href="https://golang.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Go</a></td><td>98</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200305">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>37.</td><td>RGS</td><td>brainfuck</td><td>119</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200329">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>38.</td><td>a''</td><td><a href="https://github.com/munificent/wren" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Wren</a></td><td>124</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200268">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>39.</td><td>Giuseppe</td><td><a href="http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)</a></td><td>133</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200347">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>40.</td><td>Kevin Cruijssen</td><td><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Whitespace</a></td><td>149</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200275">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>41.</td><td>Robin Ryder</td><td><a href="https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Shakespeare Programming Language</a></td><td>491</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200426">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Challenge 3 leaderboard

In the ranking below, submissions marked with a `*` are non competing.

```html
<table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> <tr><td>1.</td><td>Jonathan Allan</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Jelly</a></td><td>36</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200519">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>2.</td><td>Nick Kennedy</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Jelly</a></td><td>37</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200539">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>2.</td><td>Jonathan Allan</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V" rel="noreferrer">V (vim)</a></td><td>37</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200525">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>Expired Data</td><td><a href="https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E" rel="nofollow noreferrer">05AB1E</a></td><td>38</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200491">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>5.</td><td>Embodiment of Ignorance</td><td><a href="https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Japt</a> <a href="https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/"><code>-R</code></a></td><td>41</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200529">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>6.</td><td>Shaggy</td><td><a href="https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Japt</a></td><td>42</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200530">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>7.</td><td>ovs</td><td><a href="https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Retina</a></td><td>47</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200488">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>8.</td><td>Neil</td><td>vi</td><td>48</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200598">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>9.</td><td>Neil</td><td><a href="https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Charcoal</a></td><td>50</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200522">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>10.</td><td>Xcali</td><td><a href="https://www.perl.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Perl 5</a> <code>-p</code></td><td>58</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200512">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>11.</td><td>Mathgeek</td><td><a href="http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">GolfScript</a></td><td>62</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200541">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>12.</td><td>Mitchell Spector</td><td><a href="https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Bash</a> + Core utilities</td><td>71</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200490">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>13.</td><td>S.S. Anne</td><td><a href="https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">sed 4.2.2</a> <code>-E</code></td><td>72</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200639">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>14.</td><td>Arnauld</td><td>JavaScript (ES6)</td><td>79</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200501">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>15.</td><td>G B</td><td><a href="https://www.ruby-lang.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Ruby</a></td><td>81</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200502">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>16.</td><td>Kevin Cruijssen</td><td>Java 8</td><td>107</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200492">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>17.</td><td>Robin Ryder</td><td><a href="https://www.r-project.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">R</a></td><td>111</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200610">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>17.</td><td>isaacg</td><td><a href="https://docs.python.org/3/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Python 3</a></td><td>111</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200563">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>19.</td><td>ovs</td><td><a href="https://docs.python.org/3/" rel="noreferrer">Python 3</a></td><td>112</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200500">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>20.</td><td>wilkben</td><td><a href="http://julialang.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Julia 1.0</a></td><td>116</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200510">Link</a></td></tr><tr><td>21.</td><td>Mitchell Spector</td><td>Pure <a href="https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Bash</a></td><td>117</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200527">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Challenge 5 leaderboard

Entries marked with a `*` are non-eligible.

```html
 <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> <tr><td>1.</td><td>Grimmy</td><td><a href="https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E" rel="nofollow noreferrer">05AB1E</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200879">9</a></td></tr><tr><td>2.</td><td>Jonathan Allan</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Jelly</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200895">12</a></td></tr><tr><td>2.</td><td>Nick Kennedy</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Jelly</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200890">12</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>Embodiment of Ignorance</td><td><a href="https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Japt</a> <a href="https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/"><code>-Q</code></a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200899">13</a></td></tr><tr><td>4.</td><td>Kevin Cruijssen</td><td><a href="https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Jelly</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200883">13</a></td></tr><tr><td>6.</td><td>Jonathan Allan</td><td><a href="https://github.com/barbuz/Husk" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Husk</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200900">14</a></td></tr><tr><td>7.</td><td>Expired Data</td><td><a href="https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E" rel="nofollow noreferrer">05AB1E</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200864">17</a></td></tr><tr><td>8.</td><td>ar4093</td><td><a href="https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Pyth</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200964">20</a></td></tr><tr><td>*9.</td><td>Bubbler</td><td><a href="http://jsoftware.com/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">J</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200898">47</a></td></tr><tr><td>*10.</td><td>J42161217</td><td><a href="https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Wolfram Language (Mathematica)</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200874">63</a></td></tr><tr><td>11.</td><td>Robin Ryder</td><td><a href="https://www.r-project.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">R</a> (with partitions library)</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200924">86</a></td></tr><tr><td>12.</td><td>Neil</td><td><a href="https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Charcoal</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200916">95</a></td></tr><tr><td>13.</td><td>Christian Sievers</td><td><a href="https://www.gap-system.org/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">GAP</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200914">105</a></td></tr><tr><td>14.</td><td>Surculose Sputum</td><td><a href="https://docs.python.org/3/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Python 3</a></td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200881">112</a></td></tr><tr><td>15.</td><td>Arnauld</td><td>JavaScript (ES6)</td><td><a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200867">141</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```