# Cannot award a bounty during grace period

Tags: support

A bounty of mine expired 11 hours ago and I received an e-mail saying I had a 24-hour grace period during which I could still award the bounty. However, when I go to the [respective question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200485/75323), I do not have the usual blue buttons that would allow me to award the bounty to the answers.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I award the bounty during the grace period?

Comment: You only get a notification once it expires.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I got a notification telling me the bounty expired and approximately at the same time I got an e-mail saying I had a 24-hour grace period during which I could still award the bounty.

Comment: Yeah, the e-mail is wrong.