# Code Golf Contest(Idea)

Tags: discussion

Welcome to the idea of the Code Golf Contest, where many code golfers pit their skills against eachother in a Battle For Dream Island-esque competition!

The prize? 300 reputation!

The challenges will start easy, but will get harder and harder as the contest progresses, and one contestant will get eliminated each round.

How will they get eliminated? Glad you asked.

Each byte of code taken for each challenge is one point added to each player's score. The player with the most points at the end of each round will be eliminated until there are only 2 contestants left. Then these 2 contestants will take on the most difficult challenge of all, the championship.

The contestant with the fewest bytes used, regardless of previous challenges will be declared the winner and receive 300 reputation(the number doesn't have to be 300, it can be more or less).

**Rules**

- No cheating by looking at the answers of others.
- No answering questions if you're not part of the competition or have been eliminated.
- No hate comments on the answers of others.
- All languages are allowed, except for ones made specifically for the challenge at hand.

---

Do you like this idea of a contest? If so, pls comment on other ideas and/or rules for the contest idea!

Comment: Looks like this should be an answer in [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges).

Comment: I didnt know how to add one to sandbox but ok

Comment: @NipDip Just scroll all the way down to "Answer this Question".

Comment: How do you plan to enforce rule 1? Is this all going to happen on one question, or multiple? How many participants are you planning for, especially since you say only one will be eliminated each round?

Comment: Well Im planning for at least 8 contestants but no more than 16, and it will be a series of questions.

Answer (score 3):

> No cheating by looking at the answers of others.

This is practically unenforceable, as pointed out by Jo King in the comments

> No answering questions if you're not part of the competition or have been eliminated.

Why? What purpose does this rule serve, other than to arbitrarily exclude input? Back in February and March, there was a [meta-challenge superimposed on top of existing code golf challenges open to independent input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18545/46076), which seems to have worked.

> No hate comments on the answers of others.

This is already covered by [general network-wide policies](/conduct)

> All languages are allowed, except for ones made specifically for the challenge at hand.

This is already covered by [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/46076)

Comment: You mean, there shouldn't be any rules here in this contest?

Comment: No, I'm observing that all of the specified rules make no sense.

Comment: It's possible to have the answer key-encrypted and the key is kept by the author. The author should reveal the key after the game ends.

Comment: Ok, I might have to rethink my approach.