# Why should Brain-Flak pay for input when Python doesn't have to?

Tags: discussion

Currently if you wish to take input as a string in Brain-Flak you are going to need the `-A` flag.  This looks like:

```
$brainflak test.flk -A Hello
```

Every answer that uses this [has to add 3 bytes to its total](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions).

Currently if you would like to take input as a string in Python you are allowed to use `input()` and *assume* that the input ins provided in a proper string format ([Python IO](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11925/56656)). This looks like:

```
$echo "\"Hello World\"" | python test.py
```

This cost you no bytes (in fact it saves you bytes from having to use `raw_input()`)

This seems a little unfair, `-A` is only telling the interpreter

> Hey this thing is about to be a string don't try to interpret it as a number.

Which is pretty much the same thing that Python is doing with its quotes.

Why should `"` be considered part of the input while `-A` is considered part of the program?

Comment: Well, FWIW, in python `""` is just extra data in the input to specify the type of the input, whereas in brain-flak, `-a` modifies the way the interpreter behaves. So they're not exactly equivalent.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I don't see the distinction you are drawing, both of them specify the type of the input and both of them modify the way the interpreter behaves.

Comment: I think the distinction DJ was making was that the quotes are in the input, rather than in the interpreter. The python interpreter is not behaving differently, it is just expecting something in a certain format. While I was personally against allowing python's shortcut, it seems quite clearly different to me.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Why is `-A` not in the input?  This distinction seems rather arbitrary.  I also disagree on "The python interpreter is not behaving differently". `"` certainly doesn't modify the behavior of the python interpreter any less than `-A` modifies the Brain-Flak interpreter, they have an identical function.

Comment: `-A` functions much more like the difference between `input` and `raw_input` as far as I can tell. If that is not the case, I think you should explain that distinction better. The quotes have no affect on the python interpreter whatever, it's just data.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Perhaps I don't understand what you are saying.  How is the difference between `input` and `raw_input` different than `input` and `input` with proper quotes?

Comment: The two are different commands for the interpreter. They return a value based on expecting data in a certain manner on the standard input stream. `input(x)` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(x))`. They are similar, but different functions. What you asked is kind of similar to asking: "what is the difference between taking 2 as input and taking 1 to mean 2 by adding 1 to whatever the input is?" I hope that helps makes sense of it? Basically, one of the functions applies a transformation on the data that the other doesn't. The rule allows for the shorter one to be used. (cont'd)

Comment: This effectively allows python to take string inputs as a "python string", a different but equivalent format of data. The is no such difference in brain-flak, instead you have to tell the interpreter the data is a string. This is the same as choosing between `input` and `raw_input`, it just so happens that in python it makes the code shorter, vs longer in brain-flak.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I understand how input in python works, that's why I'm using it as the example.  `input` with proper quotes, has the *exact* same function as `raw_input`, there is no difference.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is what you are saying is untrue, since `input` performs a transformation. I won't comment anymore since I can't seem to explain this well (which is why I didn't answer), but I entirely stand by brain-flak (and any other similar language) always having to pay for the flag to change input modes.

Comment: Would this not serve better as a proposal for standard I/O?

Comment: @Shaggy I'm not proposing anything at the moment.  I'm pointing out that our system behaves strangely.

Answer (score -1):

## Make `-A` worth 1 byte

It seems to me that, like a lot of questions about the rules here, this is trying to save bytes for a specific language, in this case Brain-Flak.

I also believe that every language has a challenge specifically designed for it, whether the language knows it or not, and so every language should be able to compete fairly.

In addition to this, 3 bytes is a large penalty for such a basic task that it seems unfair, at least to me.

Therefore, I propose we make the `-A` flag for Brain-Flak worth only 1 byte. Other languages such as Perl only have 1 byte per flag and so why not allow Brain-Flak the same privilege?

Comment: The reason why Perl's flags are 1 byte and Brain-Flak's flag is 3 bytes is that in Perl you can add the `-p` flag to a normal program invocation by going from `-e "code"` to `-pe "code"`. Brain-Flak has no such `-e` flag so there is no way to add the flag for 1 byte. You always have to add a space, a hyphen and the `A`, hence 3 bytes. That may seem harsh but I think it's the only objective (and well established) way to score command-line flags and we're not going make things easier by adding special rules for specific languages like this.